# facing Socket Disconnection Challenges in Agora-Powered Live Streaming App in node.js

Tags: node.js, flutter, sockets, websocket, connection

Hello fellow developers

we are building a Live streaming mobile app in Flutter and node.js as the backend and using Agora as a live streaming provider, In parallel to Agora we are using socket.io to manage various activities such as likes, comments, and gift/coin transactions in parallel with Agora video streaming. right now we are using only a single broadcaster and multiple auidance.

The core issue we are facing arises from the frequent disconnections of sockets due to mobile network fluctuations or low network conditions.

we have tried to put some log on front end in which we are getting time out error from our server socket, but we are also logged that we have internet connection in mobile and able to ping on google at the same time from broadcaster mobile app at the same time.

kindly suggest some troubleshooting pointers to handle the sudden drop of socket connection and rejoin to socket on low network condition,

we are using node version 16

we have tried to reconnect the socket every time we got any disconnect, but we are getting timeout error from socket